# How to fix a glitch for the Oblivion walker trophy in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

I have all the Daedric artifacts and I got all of them in my inventory and everything but for some reason the game isn't giving me the trophy is this fixable? I can't platinum the game, like I would have liked  to, with out this one. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm not so sure if it's a dupe, and same could be said about the question that was duped by the one you linked. If the OP really belives it's a bug it can't be a dupe as theo ther questions don't mention bugfixes at all. Then again, the OP could be wrong

Comment: @Oak OP asked the same question twice instead of editing the first to include more information.

Comment: Did not notice that @DanmakuGrazer, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

It has been known to be a bug. Some of the things you can check/try, [source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/540733523957430916/?l=dutch)

1.

> When you did the Hircine quest, did you get both the ring and the Savior's Hide? Next time around, get both. It's a glitch and only with both of those artifacts plus others do you get the Oblivion walker achievement. If you have, however, the unofficial patch, that particular glitch is fixed, but the Oblivion Walker achievement won't trigger.

2.

> I think if you run a unofficial texture pack it has problems with the Ring of Hircine quest, so I've read on these forums. Search for it on the board cos I'm sure there was a similiar thread about not being able to get the achievement.